# Datatables search bar confused by partial view?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datatable, filtering

I am using Datatables (http://www.datatables.net) in my MVC application. Everything works as expected for all columns (paging, sorting, showing different number of elements, etc) **EXCEPT** the search bar. When I add individual search bars for each column, they all work correctly.

I have 9 columns of data. Searching works for the first 5 columns as expected, but when I attempt to filter based on the data in the last 4 columns, I get incorrect results (usually nothing gets filtered).

I believe the problem lies within my partial views. I have one partial for the table itself, and another series of partials that serve as edit windows (one for each table entry). The edit windows contain dropdowns that have all possible values for their corresponding field. I believe these edit partials are what is tripping up the filtering; perhaps the search function is seeing all the values in the drop downs, not just the selected value OF the drop down (I am not entirely sure of how the search operates). **I suspect this because when I remove the edit partials, the search feature works correctly.**

Here is my table's partial view:

```
<div id="theLog" style="width:100%; float:left; display:block">
<table class="table" id="logTable">
    @{
        var rowColor = "F2F2F2";
    }

    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#F2F2F2;">
            <th>
                Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Logged
            </th>
            <th>
                Occured
            </th>
            <th>
                Time
            </th>
            <th>
                Cleared
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
            <th>
                Location
            </th>
            <th>
                Dispatcher
            </th>
            <th>
                Officer
            </th>
            <th>
                Options
            </th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr style="background-color:@rowColor;">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreateDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IncidentDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IncidentTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeCleared)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CallType.Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CallLocation.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dispatcher.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OfficerResponding.FullNameNOID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="Edit btn btn-default" value="@item.IncidentID"  style="width: auto; padding: 4px; "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button> 
                    <button class="Delete btn btn-default" value="@item.IncidentID" style="width: auto; float: left; padding: 4px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button> 
                    <div id="editForm_@item.IncidentID" style="display: none; width: 200px" class="OfficerBox">
                        @Html.Partial("_EditIncidentPartial", item)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the part of the edit partial where the drop downs are formed

```
<div style="float: left; border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee; padding-left: 35px; width: 394px; ">
        <div class="incidentCreateFormLeft">
            <label>Call Type</label>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CallTypeID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CallTypeIDList, "", new { @style = "width:394px;" })
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: -15px">
            <label>Location</label>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CallLocationID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CallLocationIDList, "", new { @style = "width:394px;" })
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: -15px">
            <label>Dispatcher</label>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DispatcherID, (SelectList)ViewBag.DispatcherIDList, "", new { @style = "width:394px;" })
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: -15px">
            <label>Responding Officer</label>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OfficerRespondingID, (SelectList)ViewBag.OfficerRespondingIDList, "", new { @style = "width:394px;" })
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left: -15px; float: right">
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="CloseBtn" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is Datatable script:

```
$('#logTable').dataTable();
```

Everything else in my table, along with my other scripts, works. The search bar not filtering based on my last 4 columns is my only issue. I have other scripts unrelated to the datatable but the problem persists when they are all removed.

Comment: I don't think the foreign keys would be trouble, have you tried putting some random string in a column that doesn't work as test? I assume you used datatables with zero configuration too, have you tried to use individual column filter to see what happens? http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: I added the individual column filters and they work appropriately. However, the search bar at the top does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by simply disabling search on my options column

```
{ "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [9]}
```

It turns out that the problem was caused by my options column, which has all of my possible data within its HTML (in the form of drop-downs). Since all my rows had identical buttons within their options field, all rows were being detected as having he searched keyword (if that keyword was in my drop-downs), calling my "all or nothing" searches.